# How can I convert my command respond to the JSON format using bash?

Tags: json, linux, bash, shell, ubuntu

By using the ubuntu command I have a certain format for output which I wanted in JSON format but I want the implementation by using bash.

Below I have mentioned the example of JSON format

```
{
    "kernel_version": "5.15.0-46-generic",
    "operating_system": "Ubuntu 20.04.4 LTS (Focal Fossa)",
    "os_architecture": "64 Bit OS",
    "internal_ip_address": [
        "6.6.6.6",
        "7.7.7.7",
        "8.8.8.8"
    ],
    "external_ip_address": "9.9.9.9",
    "total_number_of_cpu": "8",
    "internet": "Connected",
    "uptime": "up 5 hours, 37 minutes",
    "hostname": "ubuntu",
    "users": "dummy",
    "date_and_time": "Thursday 10 January 1995 03:15:03 PM IST",
    "time_zone": "Asia/Kolkata",
    "memory": {
        "total_RAM": {
            "size1": "7.6",
            "format1": "GB"
        },
        "used_RAM": {
            "size2": "4.0",
            "format2": "GB"
        },
        "cache_memory": {
            "size3": "3.3",
            "format3": "GB"
        },
        "total_swap_memory": {
            "size4": "4.2",
            "format4": "GB"
        },
        "free_swap_memory": {
            "size5": "4.2",
            "format5": "GB"
        },
        "total_used_swap_memory": {
            "size6": "33",
            "format6": "MB"
        },
        "RAM_usage_percentage": "42.86%",
        "sec_storage_size": {
            "size7": "38",
            "format7": "GB"
        },
        "available_sec_storage": {
            "size8": "21",
            "format8": "GB"
        },
        "used_sec_storage": {
            "size9": "15",
            "format9": "GB"
        },
        "sec_storage_used_percentage": "43%"
    },
    "cpu": {
        "cpu_load": "0.48%"
    },
    "top_cpu_consuming_proc": [
        {
            "user": "val1",
            "pid": "0000",
            "cpu": "22",
            "command": "dummy1"
        },
        {
            "user": "val2+",
            "pid": "111",
            "cpu": "33",
            "command": "dummy2"
        },
        {
            "user": "val3",
            "pid": "2222",
            "cpu": "44",
            "command": "dummy3"
        }
    ]
}
```

I have tried below bash code :

```
#!/bin/bash
    echo {\"kernel_version\": \"$(uname -r)\", \
    \"operating_system\": \"$([ -f /etc/os-release ] && echo $(egrep -w "NAME|VERSION" /etc/os-release|awk -F= '{ print $2 }'|sed 's/"//g') $tecreset|| cat /etc/system-release printf"\n")\", \
    \"os_architecture\": \"$(arch | grep x86_64 &> /dev/null && printf "64 Bit OS\n"  $tecreset|| printf " 32 Bit ")\", \
    \"internal_ip_address\": $(hostname -I | awk  '
    BEGIN { ORS = ""; print "[" }
    { printf "%s\"%s\", \"%s\", \"%s\"",
          separator, $1, $2, $3, $11
      separator = ", "
    }
    END { print "]" }';), \
    \"external_ip_address\": \"$(curl -s ipecho.net/plain;echo)\", \
    \"total_number_of_cpu\": \"$(grep processor /proc/cpuinfo | wc -l)\", \
    \"internet\": \"$(ping -c 1 google.com &> /dev/null && echo -e "Connected" || echo "Disconnected")\", \
    \"uptime\": \"$(uptime -p)\", \
    \"hostname\": \"$(hostname)\", \
    \"users\": \"$(users)\", \
    \"date_and_time\": \"$(date)\", \
    \"time_zone\": \"$(cat /etc/timezone)\", \
    \"memory\": {\"total_RAM\": $(jo -a $(free -h | awk 'NR==2{printf "%s\n", $2 }' | sed 's/Gi/GB/i' | awk '{ gsub(/([[:alpha:]]+|[[:digit:].-]+|[^[:alnum:].-]+)/,"&\n",$0) ; printf $0}')), \"used_RAM\": \"$(free -h | awk 'NR==2{printf "%s\n", $3 }' | sed 's/Gi/GB/i')\", \"cache_memory\": \"$(free -h | awk 'NR==2{printf "%s\n", $6 }' | sed 's/Gi/GB/i')\", \"total_swap_memory\": \"$(free -h | awk 'NR==3{printf "%s\n", $2 }' | sed 's/Gi/GB/i')\", \"free_swap_memory\": \"$(free -h | awk 'NR==3{printf "%s\n", $4 }' | sed 's/Gi/GB/i')\", \"total_used_swap_memory\": \"$(free -h | awk 'NR==3{printf "%s\n", $3 }' | sed 's/Gi/GB/i')\", \"RAM_usage_percentage\": \"$(free -g | awk 'NR==2{printf "%.2f%%\n", $3*100/$2 }')\", \"sec_storage_size\": \"$(df -h / | awk 'NR==2{printf "%s\n", $2 }' | sed 's/G/GB/i')\", \"available_sec_storage\": \"$(df -h / | awk 'NR==2{printf "%s\n", $4 }' | sed 's/G/GB/i')\", \"used_sec_storage\": \"$(df -h / | awk 'NR==2{printf "%s\n", $3 }' | sed 's/G/GB/i')\", \"sec_storage_used_percentage\": \"$(df -h / | awk 'NR==2{printf "%s\n", $5 }')\"}, \
    \"cpu\": {\"cpu_load\": \"$(top -bn1 | grep load | awk '{printf "%.2f%%\n", $(NF-2)}')\"}}
```

I can get the result but I cannot make it for JSON. I have to follow through bash script.
Anyone could you please let me know about the solution with proper example.

Comment: Unclear what you're asking. You're showing JSON that you want to convert to JSON?

Comment: We wanted to achieve the JSON format shown in the example by using the bash command.

Comment: That is great, what format are you getting though? And what have you tried to convert it so far?

Comment: So what do expect from us? Random guess the output of some random bash command and then say how to convert those? Please read [ask] and [edit] your post to add a [mre].

Comment: I have edited my question with what I had tried with bash script.

Comment: Use the `jq` command to generate JSON instead of cobbling it together using string interpolation.

Comment: Yes! I tried jq and jo, but it only works for some of the commands, and I'm not getting the desired results. Could you please provide an example?

Comment: sed 's/Gi/GB/' is a terrible idea.  The question of whether a Gig is 1073741824 or 100000000 bytes is ambiguous enough without this.

Answer (score 1):

Use a heredoc as a template. Here's an example that gives you the first few fields that you want:

```
#!/bin/sh

jq . << EOF
{
    "kernel_version": "$(uname -r)",
    "operating_system": "$(awk '$1 == "NAME"{printf "%s ", $3 } $1 == "VERSION" {print $3}' FS=[=\"] /etc/os-release)",
    "os_architecture": "$(arch)",
    "internal_ip_address": [
        $(hostname -I | sed -e 's/^/"/' -e 's/ *$/",/' -e '$s/,$//')
    ]
}
EOF
```

Comment: "here-string" documents work well for this sort of thing too, though I think the quoting might be messier.

Comment: Please help me out on jq or jo.

Comment: @Devil What do you mean by "help me out on jq"?  You could verify the template and get standardized output by replacing `cat` with `jq .`, which is probably a good idea.  I'll edit the answer to do that.

Comment: Below command splits the result and stores the result as key and value pair using jo. But the issue is i am getting the message like Argument 'GB' is neither k=v nor k@v.    Here is the command -   `jo -p $(free -h | awk 'NR==2{printf "%s\n", $2 }' | sed 's/Gi/GB/i' | sed 's/Mi/MB/i' | awk '{ gsub(/([[:alpha:]]+|[[:digit:].-]+|[^[:alnum:].-]+)/,"&\n",$0) ; print "K="$0 "L="$2}')`

Comment: Here is the result - `Argument 'GB' is neither k=v nor k@v
{
   "K": 7.6,
   "L": "GB"
}`